# Issue with version of css files in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, version

I have an issue with versions of css files on my site, wordpress engine.

I have a file

`/wp-content/uploads/wp-less/dt-the7/css/custom-3bd5941b9d.css`

I edited it and still can't see any changes on my site.

So I tried to inspect a code, and I noticed that site uses css file with another version

`(/wp-content/uploads/wp-less/dt-the7/css/custom-3bd5941b9d.css?ver=3.5.1)`

So my question is:

Where can I find exactly `custom-3bd5941b9d.css?ver=3.5.1` file? Or is it just a cache in database? If so - how can I edit it?

Comment: it is coming from cache. Check plugins section are you using any cache plugin?

Comment: it may come from your **browser** cache, or a plugin cache or even a cache related to other services like cloudfare. Try to clear your cache

Comment: concerning the **ver=3.5.1** it's only a query to force your browser to fetch the file again, so whataver he version is, the file is still the same

Comment: and seeing the name of the file **custom-3bd5941b9d.css** for sure you are using a cache plugin, so you need to purge the cache

Comment: you should not edit the cached version - so forget about finding that file - concern yourself with clearing your cache in either your plugin, or if it is wpengine, even in your enviroment

Comment: Ok so I have 'WP super cache' plugin. What should I do with it? If I remove cache will I lose and data?

Comment: only the cached data - it will just be refetched - it is always safe to clear your cache - but sometimes your site might be acting weird if you go into it soon after clearing. this cache is to speed up your website. if you are in a development stage, and don't have users on your page, i would recommend disabling it while you develop

Comment: Ok, so I checked 'WP super cache' and it actualy was disabled. In a tab with 'cache info' there was a line 'cache size 0' so cache is empty. 
Just in case I updated plugin. No changes tho. 
Any other type of cache? Where can I find it? Any suggestions? :)

Comment: If you use cloudflare, they'll also cache images, js, and css. Turn on the development mode for the site in question if you are not seeing changes.
Also use your browser's developer tools to disable client side caching.

Comment: I did not use cloudflare. But seems deleting a chace in WP super cache plugin helped. I've just opened a new browser and it seems to work well. Thanks for your help!